# DateTime Flutter

Tags: time, dart, flutter, clock

How do I implement the current time into Text format? I feel like it should be fairly simple but struggling to do so.

Basic example;

[image]

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579740/2461957

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579740/7015400) and changing it a bit:-

You can try the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';



void main() {
 runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss \n EEE d MMM').format(now);
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),text: "Alarm",),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),text:"Clock" ,),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.timer),text:"Timer"),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
          Center(child: Text(formattedDate,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0),)),
          Icon(Icons.timer),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Should give you this:

[image: flutter image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to make the time stay up to date? Would it need an animation class?

Comment: No, just a timer that calls `setState`. There's an interesting article [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-fast-is-flutter-i-built-a-stopwatch-app-to-find-out-9956fa0e40bd).

Comment: Note that DateFormat is relatively expensive to construct (for one thing, it has to parse the format string), so it would be better not to rebuild that each time.

Comment: how to date countdown from now until chosen date?

Comment: @RichardHeap can ```StreamBuilder``` be useful for this task?

Answer (score 18):

**In flutter 1.20 :**

`DateTime now = DateTime.now();`

`print(now.hour.toString() + ":" + now.minute.toString() + ":" + now.second.toString());`

Answer (score 9):

To get the current Time in AM/PM format.

`dynamic currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.now());`

Comment: Your answer is really helpful just want to know one thing how to get the time in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 8):

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var formatterDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yy');
var formatterTime = DateFormat('kk:mm');
String actualDate = formatterDate.format(now);
String actualTime = formatterTime.format(now);
```

Answer (score 4):

To set a continuous running clock:

```
void initState() {
_timeString = _formatTime(DateTime.now());

Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTimeString());
super.initState();
```

}

Then use to get time:

```
_getTimeString() {
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final String formattedTime = _formatTime(now);

setState(() {
  _timeString = formattedTime;    
});
```

}

Use to format time:

```
String _formatTime(DateTime dateTime) {
return DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
```

}

To display the time, create a text widget and use

```
'$_timeString'
```

to display continuously updating clock.

Answer (score 0):

pick a exact time in flutter app and put in local notification package...full detail guide.//(alarm App)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBD77.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).