# Flutter/Dart - Format Date in input form

Tags: date, flutter, datetime, dart

How can I format the date and change from:

[image: current output]

to just dd/mm/yyyy?

input field code:

```
    textFields.add(
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 12.0
          ),
          controller: _date,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            hintText: 'Date of Birth',
            filled: true,
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.0),
            ),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
          ),
          onSaved: (value) => _dateOfBirth  = value,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

_selectDate method:

```
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController _date = new TextEditingController();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        _date.value = TextEditingValue(text: picked.toString());
      });
  }
```

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579546/how-to-format-datetime-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateFormat` class of the [intl package](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html). You'll have to add `intl: ^0.16.1` as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml`. Latest version can be found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install).

You can specify the exact format you want your date to be outputted as.

Ex.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';//Import intl in the file this is being done

Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');//specifies day/month/year format

    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        _date.value = TextEditingValue(text: formatter.format(picked));//Use formatter to format selected date and assign to text field
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();   //current date
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // use any format
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
```

if     you have date picker than

```
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // use any formate
    String formatted = formatter.format(picked);
```