# Convert epoch time into timestamp flutter

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I have a date-time in epoch format: 1633247247

I want to convert it into timestamps like this: Sunday, 3 October 2021 or just October 3 2021

I am writing this code

```
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1633247247);
```

But it is returning 1970-01-19 18:25:11.247

Edit I ran this code

```
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1633247247 * 1000);
```

Got the output in datetime. I am now trying to convert into string

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(date);
```

It gives this error  `The instance member 'date' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Download and Import**

[intl Pacakge](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

**Initialize a variable**

```
String datetime;
```

**Get Current date and conversion**

```
Future<void> Datetimes() async{
  setState(() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('EEEE d MMM hh:mm:ss').format(now);
    datetime=formattedDate;
  });
}
```

**Output**

```
Saturday 3 oct 2:07:29
```

Refer this for DateandTime class for more formatting parameters
[DateFormat-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: how can I pass my current value?

Comment: you mean the formatted date,if that is you can access the `datetime` variable anywhere@ajay131

Comment: this returns null

Comment: did you call `Datetimes` function in initState()@ajay131

Comment: did you downloaded the package and imported it,if it is done ,try this ,`Text(datetime.toString()) then `run `flutter clean ` and run again @ajay131

Answer (score 4):

It represent to milliseconds, you need to multiple it with 1000 like below :

> final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1633247247 * 1000);

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that the time you've is 'seconds since epoch' so just multiplying by 1000 should give you the correct time.

```
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1633247247 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **DateTime Formats**. You can find a solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579740/11604909