# How to assign nested json object to a datamodel and acces the properties with flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a json book object which has these nested properties in it:

```
"books": [
    {
      "book_id": 1,
      "book_name": "Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone",
      "year_published": 1997,
      "month_published": 6,
      "week_published": 25,
    },
    {
      "book_id": 2,
      "book_name": "Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets",
      "year_published": 1998,
      "month_published": 7,
      "week_published": 26,
    },
```

How can i map this nested json object into datamodel and acces the mapped object's properties? Also how can i combine year_publishedand and month_published into DateTime object and acces it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a Books Model class which looks like this:

```
 class BooksModel {
  List<Books> books;

  BooksModel({this.books});

  BooksModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['books'] != null) {
      books = new List<Books>();
      json['books'].forEach((v) {
        books.add(new Books.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.books != null) {
      data['books'] = this.books.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Books {
  int bookId;
  String bookName;
  int yearPublished;
  int monthPublished;
  int weekPublished;

  Books(
      {this.bookId,
      this.bookName,
      this.yearPublished,
      this.monthPublished,
      this.weekPublished});

  Books.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    bookId = json['book_id'];
    bookName = json['book_name'];
    yearPublished = json['year_published'];
    monthPublished = json['month_published'];
    weekPublished = json['week_published'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['book_id'] = this.bookId;
    data['book_name'] = this.bookName;
    data['year_published'] = this.yearPublished;
    data['month_published'] = this.monthPublished;
    data['week_published'] = this.weekPublished;
    return data;
  }
}
```

To Assign data to it you can do that:

> List booksModel= [];

> booksModel = await fetchBooks();

And to show you how your fetchBooks() function should look like this can be done:

```
 Future<List<BookModel>> fetchBooks() async {
var result = //Get your json data from Api
List jsonReponse = result.toList();
return jsonReponse.map((book) => new BookModel.fromJson(book)).toList();
```

}

To access that data you could use a Futurebuilder or a statemanagment solution such as Provider

an Example for Futurebuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<List<BookModel>>(
  future: fetchBooks(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<BookModel>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return //LoadingWidget
    } else {
    List<BookModel> bookModelList = snapshot.data;
      return Text(bookModelList.books[0].bookId);
    }
  },
);
```

> With the solution above a listviewbuilder is nessecary and remember to replace 0 with index from listview.

##**Note: This solution is untested and should just point you in the right direction**##

**Also if your JsonResponse contains more data you need to update model class.
Here is a helpful tool for generating Model classes**

```
https://jsontodart.com/
```

For the DateTime feature you mentioned you might need to do like an unix time to datetime convertion [Convert epoch time into timestamp flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182241/convert-epoch-time-into-timestamp-flutter)

In your Futurebuilder listview you can use row widget to show beside each other