# How do I format Date in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to output my date like this " Today is Feb 25, 2018 ", it is possible? using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package?

Comment: I guess 'Today is ' needs to be concatenated to the output of date time formatter. You cant get something like that directly

Comment: I see. what about "Feb 25, 2018"? it is possible?

Comment: DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(your_date_time)
Pls check here for ref -> 
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Acutally I am not flutter dev :D , but its straight forward

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format DateTime in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579546/how-to-format-datetime-in-flutter)

Comment: yes @R.Shpd. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to use formatDate
For example:

```
Text('Today is 'formatDate(checkDate, [dd, '/', mm, '/', yyyy, ' '])
```