# How to format DateTime in Flutter? Remove milliseconds in DateTime?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

As you seen, i have a custom DatePicker widget and it takes the **currentTime** in **DateTime** type.

```
 DatePickerWidget(
                    currentTime: DateTime.now(),
                    text: "$date1",
                    onChanged: (date) {
                      setState(() {
                        getProductDate(date.toString());
                        this.date1 = date.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    onConfirm: (date) {
                      setState(() {
                        getProductDate(date.toString());

                        this.date1 = date.toString();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

but it's give me milliseconds too.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLUjD.png)

**Result**

YYYY-MM-JJ  HH-MM:00.000

How can I remove the :00.000 part in DateTime type?

I just want to this format: **'yyyy-MM-dd'**.

But **currentTime** is getting only **DateTime** type.

is there any idea?

my DatePickerWidget code:

```
class DatePickerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(DateTime data) onChanged;
  final Function(DateTime data) onConfirm;
  final String text;
  final DateTime currentTime;

 
 

  const DatePickerWidget(
      {Key key, this.onChanged, this.onConfirm, this.text, this.currentTime})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonWidget(
      onPressed: () {
        DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
            theme: DatePickerTheme(
              containerHeight: context.dynamicHeight(0.3),
            ),
            showTitleActions: true,
            minTime: DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
            maxTime: DateTime(2028, 12, 29),
            onChanged: onChanged,
            onConfirm: onConfirm,
            currentTime: currentTime,
            locale: LocaleType.tr);
      },
      text: text,
      buttonColor: Colors.white,
      borderColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.black,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format DateTime in Flutter , How to get current time in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579546/how-to-format-datetime-in-flutter-how-to-get-current-time-in-flutter)

Comment: no, i already checked that too. My problem is different :/

Comment: Different how? It's an *exact* duplicate. Why is your problem different?

Comment: sir, my currentTime is getting only "DateTime" type. I checked all solutions from your questions and doesn't work on me :(

Comment: which code is displaying the date? I mean from your image.

Comment: the  text: "$date1", is displaying  the date.  If user select the date, i am going to display the selected date in button's text.

Comment: And why is none of those answers helping you? Any single one is producing the output you want. Maybe I did not understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [Jiffy](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy), to make it easier to work with date and time

To format your DateTime just pass in your result `date`, see below

```
this.date1 = Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(date).format('yyyy-MM-dd'); // 2021-03-24

// or you can also use default formats

this.date1 = Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(date).yMMMMd; // March 24, 2021
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `DateFormat` from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(now);
```

You can also do it without adding a dependecy

```
DateTime.now()
            .toString()
            .substring(0,10)
     );
```

0

Comment: my currentTime is only getting "DateTime" type. So your code is doesn't work on me :/

Answer (score 2):

You will need the package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
final now = DateTime.now();
String dateFormatted = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
```

Comment: my currentTime is only getting "DateTime" type. So your code is doesn't work on me :/

Comment: It doesn't change anything you just have to do  `String dateFormatted = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(currentTime);`

Answer (score 0):

Here in place of "MillisecondsSinceEpoch"  put your value

```
var startDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse("MillisecondsSinceEpoch"));
```

Comment: value is like what?

Comment: your converted MillisecondsSinceEpoch