# How to remove last 3 numbers from this line? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello there i have this Datacells and i want to remove the last 3 numbers,
here is my code line :

```
DataCell(Text((DateTime.parse(e['start'].toString()).toLocal().toString()))),
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean the word "333"?

Comment: yes i want to remove that 333

Comment: I suggest using [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#date-formatting-and-parsing) for formatting `DateTime` objects.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349547/how-to-format-datetime-in-flutter-remove-milliseconds-in-datetime)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil user wants to remove miliseconds from a date, not elements from list as is in your linked answer

Comment: @vladli ohh I got it what exact he want, Thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
DataCell(Text((DateTime.parse(e['start'].toString()).toLocal().toString()).replaceAll(".333", ""))),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take this as an example:

```
final text = "2022-06-12 16:34:45:333";
print(text.substring(0, text.length-4)); // 2022-06-12 16:34:45
```

This will remove the last 3 letters and ":"  from it.

Another solution, you can also do this:

```
  final text = "2022-06-12 16:34:45:333";
  final asList = text.split(":");
  asList.removeLast();
  print(asList.join(":")); // 2022-06-12 16:34:45
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **substring** method on the string you get;
In particular, you can first calculate how the string should look like:

```
String dateString = DateTime.parse(e['start'].toString()).toLocal().toString();
String truncatedDateString = dateString.substring(0, dateString.length - 4);
```

and then use the truncatedDateString variable in your DataCell:

```
DataCell(Text(truncatedDateString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply take the first 20 characters

```
DateTime.parse(e['start'].toString()).toLocal().toString().substring(0,19); //2022-06-01 14:28:56
```

or as [mmcdon20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080848/mmcdon20) said use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#date-formatting-and-parsing)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
...
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm:ss').format(now); //2022-12-19 – 10:32:05
```